# Forming a splitting of $R^2$

Tags: general-topology

In my topology course i recently learned about the concept of a splitting and using it to assist in determining whether a set is connected or not. So I am trying to determine if a subset in $R^2$ is connected that has the subspace topology induced on it coming from the standard topology on $R^2$. But i am having an issue successfully splitting up $R^2$ in order to get open sets to use in the subspace topology. Any suggestions? Is it even possible? Because here thinking about it, i can't come up with any

The set is $$X = \{(x,y): xy = 1 \} $$

Comment: Draw a picture of $X$. Oops, that's just half of $X$ - once you have an accurate picture of $X$ in mind this should be clear

Comment: For the set X i got lines that will never be able to reach the axis in the first an d tnird quadrant of the x-y plane, but now the questio  is how do i split $R^2$ using the standard topology?

Comment: Hold on....thinking about it more, do i even NEED to split $R^2$?  Idea: let B (x,y) be my ball of a radius delta around a point, so if i take two of these, these are just open sets in R^2 and since i am going to be intersecting them with my splitted set in X then i could solve for connectedness.

Comment: Ok - I assumed you were missing the part in the third quadrant. The definition of "split" is not clear to me. All you need is two disjoint open sets $U$ and $V$ so $U$ contains one of those two curves and $V$ contains the other one. ("Split $\mathbb R^2$" sounds like $\mathbb R^2$ has to be the union of $U$ and $V$. Not so..)

Comment: Yes that is correct we defined splitting as $ U\cup V = X $ and $U\cap V=\empty $. Those two condition define a splitting. And since it is in the subspace topology i need open sets from $R^2$

Comment: Ok. The word "split" is not so standard here - if you'd said "disconnection" I would have been certain what you meant. So anyway, you don't need to split $\mathbb R^2$, which is good because that's impossible. You just need to split $X$. And for that you just need two open subsets of the plane such that [what I said in previous comment].

Comment: After going over my notes i noticed something just like you mentioned. So it suffices to find just one splitting either the over arching set or like in this case a splitting of the subset and then using the subspace topology criteria to create my splitting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really need to split $\mathbb{R}^2$ to show that some subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ is not connected. You just need to find subsets of $\mathbb{R}^2$ which are open with empty intersection and they should *cover the given subset (and not $\mathbb{R}^2$).*

So for your set the open left and right half planes will do the job. Or if you want you can actually go with the first and the third quadrant itself.